# Jekyll: How to get markdown parsing inside blocks using Kramdown?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

Per the Kramdown docs, setting the option `parse_block_html` should allow for processing of markdown (Kramdown) syntax inside html blocks.

In my `_config.yml`, I have the settings as:

```
---
name: Blog Name
markdown: kramdown
kramdown: 
  parse_block_html: true
---
```

Then in a post .md file, I try something like:

```
# Headline1
------------

<div>
  # Headline2
  ------------
</div>
```

The markdown content inside the div is not translated into HTML upon `jekyll build`. What am I missing? (Also, is there an easier way to do it in any of the other markdown syntaxes, e.g. RedCarpet?)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to use an inner declaration, and remove indentation (unless you want it to be treated as code):

```
# Headline1
------------

{::options parse_block_html="true" /}
<div>
# Headline2
------------
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, the indent inside the div was the issue, indeed. Don't need the `{::options }` inner declaration even. Sweet!

Answer (score 30):

You can add a `markdown="1"` attribute to your `<div>`, if I read well [the HTML Blocks part of the Kramdown doc](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks):

> If an HTML tag has an attribute markdown="1", then the default mechanism for parsing syntax in this tag is used.

```
# Headline1
------------

<div markdown="1">
  # Headline2
  ------------
</div>
```